# How to set attribute in XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

For example, I want to add an attribute to this node:

```
<Party>
```

So it will look like:

```
<Party role="this should be set using XPath">
```

Attribute value has to come from XPath.

The following will not work :)

```
<Party role=<xsl:value-of select="some/xpath/path"/>>
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Attributes of literal result elements support the *attribute value template* syntax, using `{}`:

```
<Party role="{some/xpath/path}">
```

Answer (score 14):

```
<xsl:template match="Party">
  <Party role="{some/xpath/path}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </Party>
</xsl:template>
```

should do. As an alternative

```
<xsl:template match="Party">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="role" select="some/xpath/path"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course the apply-templates is only necessary if there are attribute and/or child nodes you also want to be processed (for example to be copied by an identity transformation template).

Answer (score 8):

you can try the below sample:

```
<xsl:for-each select="YOUR_SELECT_PATH"> 
  <a> 
    <Party> <xsl:attribute name="role"><xsl:value-of select="@source"/></xsl:attribute> </Party>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
  </a> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Here I am setting the attribute role to a xml node Party.